# Almacenar un array de Angular a una base de datos MySQL

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, angular7

Se genera un array con datos que el usuario debe llenar, pero imaginando que el array ya está llenado y en este caso es el siguiente:

```
sucursalArray: SucursalC[] = [
   {pais: "México"; estado: "Quintana Roo"},
   {pais: "México"; estado: "Campeche"},
   {pais: "México"; estado: "Puebla"},
   {pais: "México"; estado: "Ciudad de México"},
];
```

¿Cómo podría guardarlo en mi base de datos? Si quiero guardar en este caso 4 filas distintas

Agrego información extra.

> sucursal.ts

```
export class SucursalC {
  id: number = 0;
  pais: string;
  estado: string;
}
```

> sucursales.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SucursalC } from '../models/sucursal';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SucursalesService {

  API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSucursales() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/sucursal`);
  }

  getSucursal(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/sucursal/${id}`);
  }

  deleteSucursal(id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.API_URI}/sucursal/${id}`);
  }

  saveSucursal(sucursal: SucursalC) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URI}/sucursal`, sucursal);
  }

  updateSucursal(id: string, updatedSucursal: SucursalC) {
    return this.http.put(`${this.API_URI}/sucursal/${id}`, updatedSucursal);
  }
}
```

> La tabla sucursales de mi BD

```
CREATE TABLE sucursales_empresas(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_empresa INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_empresa) REFERENCES empresas (id),
  pais VARCHAR(50),
  estado VARCHAR(50),
  fecha_creacion DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  status_bd VARCHAR(2)
);
```

**En este momento solo estoy enviando el pais y el estado, es lo que quiero que se guarde por ahora, los demás campos ignorenlos**

Como backend estoy utilizando **Express** y para conectarme a la tabla sucursales_empresas tengo lo siguiente:

> sucursalesController.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

import pool from '../../database';

class SucursalesController{

   public async list (req: Request, res: Response) {
        const sucursales = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sucursales_empresas');
        res.json(sucursales);
   }

   public async getOne (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
      const { id } = req.params;
      const sucursales = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sucursales_empresas WHERE id = ?', [id]);
      if (sucursales.length > 0){
         return res.json(sucursales[0]);
      }
      res.status(404).json({text: 'No existe'});
 }

   public async create (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
      await pool.query('INSERT INTO sucursales_empresas set ?', [req.body])
      res.json({text: 'Sucursal creada'});
   }

   public async update (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
      const { id } = req.params;
      await pool.query('UPDATE sucursales_empresas set ? WHERE id = ?', [req.body, id]);
      res.json({message: 'La sucursal fue actualizada'});
   }

   public async delete (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
     const { id } = req.params;
     await pool.query('DELETE FROM sucursales_empresas WHERE id = ?', [id])
     res.json({message: 'La sucursal fue eliminada'});
   }

}

export const sucursalesController = new SucursalesController();
export default sucursalesController;
```

> sucursalesRoutes.ts

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import sucursalesController from 
'../../controllers/empresas/sucursalesController';

class SucursalesRoutes {

    public router: Router = Router();

    constructor() {
        this.config();
    }

    config(): void {
        this.router.get('/', sucursalesController.list);
        this.router.get('/:id', sucursalesController.getOne);
        this.router.post('/', sucursalesController.create);
        this.router.put('/:id', sucursalesController.update);
        this.router.delete('/:id', sucursalesController.delete);
    }

}

const sucursalesRoutes = new SucursalesRoutes();
export default sucursalesRoutes.router;
```

Comment: Primero debes configurar un backend para enviar ahí esos datos. Angular no puede interactuar con la base de datos directamente.

Comment: Ya tengo el backend para hacer la inserción de datos pero no sé cómo realizarla si tengo un array de muchas filas

Comment: Está bien, entonces edita tu pregunta y  agrega más información necesaria para ayudarte: en que lenguaje está el backend, el código donde recibes los datos que angular envía, etc

Comment: La información que agregué es suficiente?

Comment: @CesarPalos Debes  agregar en que tienes el código del backend  es en `C#` `java` `php` y como tienes estructurada la tabla para poder ayudarte, cual es el problema en si no llegan los datos al backEnd desde angular  ? o  llegan pero no están guardando de la forma que quieres ?

Comment: Okay, en un momento agrego eso que mencionas y el problema es que no sé cómo enviar la consulta para que me almacene todo de una sola vez

Comment: A que te refieres con todo de una sola vez ? @CesarPalos

Comment: O sea, enviar todos los datos del array juntos y que se almacenen los 4 registros, no cuando se hace un formulario que se manda 1 solo registro por vez, ya agregue lo demás @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO

Comment: Este es el metodo que crea la sucursal? public async create (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
      await pool.query('INSERT INTO sucursales_empresas set ?', [req.body])
      res.json({text: 'Sucursal creada'});

Comment: La variable donde llega el array es cual `req` ??

Comment: Ese método es el que uso en mi ruta "this.router.post('/', sucursalesController.create);" que se encuentra en sucursalesRoutes.ts y el [req.body] son los valores que le mando desde mi sucursales.service.ts con el siguiente método "saveSucursal(sucursal: SucursalC) {return this.http.post(`${this.API_URI}/sucursal`, sucursal);}"

Comment: La verdad no conozco mucho de express , pero supongo que tienes que recorrer el array con un foreachs y realizar un insert por cada reigstro del array.

Comment: No se me había ocurrido esa idea, voy a intentarlo y comentaré si me funciona, gracias bro

Comment: Ya lo logre como me comentaste, de verdad muchas gracias por la idea y todo

Comment: Dale, agrega la solución para que ayudes a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La **solución** que me funcionó fue usar un bucle for con el cual recorrer mi arreglo y así guardar una por una las sucursales, adjunto el código del método por si le sirve a alguien:

```
test() {
  for (let suc of this.sucursalArray) {
    delete suc.id;
    this.sucursalesService.saveSucursal(suc).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**Gracias a "FRANCISCO J. BLANCO" por darme la idea.**